# I want to click on link and not go to other html page but echo a page. Is that posible in php

Tags: php

How can I use php to echo a page instead of linking to existing html page with hyperlink?

One example would be

```html
<html>
<body>

<a href="http:...">click on this link to go back</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, I don't want this link above to be a link to html page but to echo a page with php code when user clicks on **click on this link to go back**(to generate a page). This way, nobody can access a page after they logout.
Can php do this?

Comment: what you want to do? revert logout?

Comment: No one can access the page after they log out. That is the whole point. If you clear everything that's required to identify a person as logged in, then where's the problem? This isn't related to PHP or HTML at all. There is no problem. Are you talking about preventing the back button on the browser after someone logs out?

Comment: I can't really get what you want

Comment: try to use php session or cookie:

Comment: If you want a solid login system : use sessions. If you want to keep the url constant use iframes, ajax or stuff like that. If you want sth else , rewrite your question

Comment: Read now, i edited question so i hope i explained it better...

Answer (score 1):

If someone logged out of your website or application I assume you will have a check whether or not this person is allowed to view the content.

Your question itself is very unclear to me. But it sound a bit if you want to do client-side coding (don't follow a link when it's clicked) with PHP which is not possible since PHP is a server side language. You will need Javascript to change the behavior of a link (for example, make an AJAX request which returns the content of another page).

Answer (score 0):

`Create a function`, what the function should do is it should get triggered on a  `button click event` and the code inside the function must send an `curl` request to the **url** you want and get back the html from it and echo it on your page

For answering the second part of your question!. you want no one to access the data without logging in so maintain `$_SERVER[''];` and `sessions` for users and validate if the user is inside a genuine session then show him content else no